# Calling virtual method from base class C++

Tags: c++, function, virtual

I'm new to C++ and i'm having a hard time figuring out what's wrong with my virtual functions. So, here's what i have:
**GEntity.h**

```
class GEntity
{
public:
    //...
    virtual void tick(void);
    virtual void render(void);
    //...
};
```

**GEntity.cpp**

```
//...
void GEntity::tick(void){}
void GEntity::render(void){}
//...
```

**GLiving.h**

```
class GLiving : public GEntity
{
public:
    //...
    virtual void tick(void);
    virtual void render(void);
    //...
};
```

**GLiving.cpp**

```
//...
void GEntity::tick(void){}
void GEntity::render(void){}
//...
```

Then i have other classes that derive from GLiving (Player, Enemy) which implement their own versions of this two methods:
**Player.h**

```
class Player : public GLiving
{
public:
    //...
    void tick(void);
    void render(void);
    //...
};
```

**Player.cpp**

```
//...
void GEntity::tick(void)
{
    //Here there's some actual code that updates the player
}
void GEntity::render(void)
{
    //Here there's some actual code that renders the player
}
//...
```

Now, if i declare an object of class Player, and call the render/tick method, everything goes well, but i am in a situation in which i add my player to an arraylist (a struct i created) of GEntity, and then, when i get it back, i get it as a GEntity, and i need to call the render/tick methods without knowing it's derived class...
I've tried with the code above, but i get an access violation in the line where i call either the render or tick method, on the extracted GEntity...
...is what i want even possible to achieve?
(sorry if my english is not so good, but i'm italian)

Comment: The problem probably exists in your `arraylist`.  Does it contain pointers to `GEntity` or actual instances of `GEntity`?

Comment: What about the array/struct declaration? That holds the key.

Comment: it contains actual instances

Comment: It looks like you are experiencing [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: You need pointers, not instances. Use smart pointers for preference.

Comment: In your `.cpp` files, it should be `GLiving::tick` and `Player::tick` instead of `GEntity::tick`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an array of `GEntity` then, each time you "add" a derived type, the equivalent of this happens:

```
GEntity g;
Player p;
g = p; // object slicing, you assigned a Player to a GEntity object.
g.render(); // GEntity::render() gets called
```

On the other hand, you can use a pointer to a base class to access a derived method:

```
GEntity* g;
Player p;
g = &p;
g->render(); // calls Player::render()
```

So a way to deal with polymorphism in containers is to have arrays/containers of (preferably smart) pointers to the base class. This example uses raw pointers for simplicity, but you should use [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) in real code:

```
std::vector<CEntity*> entities;
entities.push_back(new Player);
entities.push_back(new GLiving);

// some c++11
for ( auto e : entities) {
  e->render();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you write `for (_auto_ e : entities)`?